# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. "Kubernetes on Docker for Windows"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

I have installed the Edge version of Docker for Windows 18.05.0-ce (Windows 10 Hyper-V) and enabled Kubernetes afterwards.
On my other machine a kubectl context was created automatically, but on this new machine it was not.

```
> kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME      CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Can i some how make Docker for Windows create the context?
Or can I set it up manually?
I am a little unsure how to get the infomation needed for the `kubectl config set-context` command.

I can run docker containers outside of Kubernetes.
I see the Kubernetes containers running inside Docker.

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND
8285ca0dd57a        353b8f1d102e                     "kube-scheduler --ad…"
3b25fdb0b7a6        40c8d10b2d11                     "kube-controller-man…"
e81db90fa68e        e03746fe22c3                     "kube-apiserver --ad…"
2f19e723e0eb        80cc5ea4b547                     "/kube-dns --domain=…"
etc...
```

Comment: I am trying to use the kubernetes shipped with Docker for Desktop ( Windows 10 ). The issue for me is that I haven't enabled it in docker settings. Resolved automatically after enabling kubernetes in docker settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with docker for windows when the `HOMEDRIVE` is set by a corporate policy.

If you set the `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable to `C:\Users\my_username\.kube\config` (make sure the `$HOME` environment variables expand, don't use `$HOME` itself.), it should work.

Further info: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1651

Answer (score 4):

I found that Docker for Windows correctly updated my kubectl config file, but on Windows 10 Enterprise there is no environment variable called "HOME".

So kubectl cant find the config file, `C:\users\{userid}\.kube\config`

Adding environment variable `HOME=C:\users\{userid}` solved the issue on my machine.

See: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2066

Answer (score -2):

Run commands to overcome (connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) issue.

```
minikube delete 
minikube start
```

Answer (score -2):

When i had this issue it was because minikube was not running. Ensure minikube is up and running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).